# How can i call the menu power in android xamarin?

Tags: android, xamarin, menu

[image: screenshot]

I want to show that with something like `Android.Provider.Settings`, to start a new activity

Comment: You want to display a popup alert to start a new activity?

Comment: Not really, i want that system tool to appear when i click a button

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately that will not be available to you

Here is a list of settings you could possibly launch within a new intent

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Provider.Settings/

power settings is not one of them.

Comment: ComponentName component = new ComponentName(getApplicationContext(), PowerMenuService.class);
    getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().setComponentEnabledSetting(component, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED,
            PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);

    Intent intent = new Intent("com.yourapp.ACCESSIBILITY_ACTION");
    intent.putExtra("action", AccessibilityService.GLOBAL_ACTION_POWER_DIALOG);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: It is supposed to be posible with this, but that is not for Android xamarin

Comment: also thank you for you answer, that was very helpful

Comment: No problem, in order to use it with Xamarin, Xamarin itself will need to have a wrapper for it. Which it does not. Not all android native features are available in Xamarin.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I get your idea but still i do not know how to use it.

Comment: That was my point. You cannot use it. The only way you could use that is if you were writing native java for android development. Xamarin will not let you